# Create a Collection of Objects from a Class Using a Transformer Function

Tags: php, collections, dependency-injection, static, factory

In this question I would like to discuss a problem related to building a collection of homogeneous objects from a class using a transformer function that transforms a passed array or other sort of collection. The problem lies in the fact that I want to be able to see from which class are the objects in a collection when doing the transofrmation and at the same time avoid using statics as we all know they are kind of tricky and the general recommendation is to avoid them.

The scenario is the following:

- There is an abstract class that does some common parsing of data (formatting dates, strings, floats, etc.) called `AbstractData`. Its purpose is to be extended by more concrete classes which make use of the abstract functions and hold the parsed data.
- The concrete class uses a mapping array which tells how given raw data has to be parsed using the functions from the abstract class.

Currently what is being done to create a collection of such concrete class objects is the following (take care that the constructor of the Concrete class takes single row of data which it parses automatically using the defined mapping scheme):

```
collection = [];
foreach($rows as $row) {
    collection = new ConcreteClass($row);
}
```

What I have here basically is just an array of those objects, but I was wondering what would be the best way to keep a more structured collection the same way you could do using generics in Java like `List<ConcreteClass> collection = new List<ConcreteClass>(row);`

Right now what I did was to make a static "factory" function in the abstract class:

```
public static function factory($data = null) {
    return new static($data); 
}
```

And a function that creates the "processed" collection:

```
public function createCollectionFromRawData($rows) {
    $collection = [];
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $collection[] = new static($row);
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

And call the concrete class like this: `ConcreteClass::factory()->createCollectionFromRawData($rows)`

And although it allows for better reading in a way it is a bit redundant since it does not separate concerns and additionally I have to create an empty object of the ConcreteClass just to be able to invoke the non-static createCollectionFromRawData function which I would like to avoid doing.

I was thinking something in the lines of involving DI to solve the problem but I am not really sure what exactly I can do.

Comment: _".. most clean code as possible .. "_ this is going to be heavily opinion-based. Possibly rewording this into a "What are the pros/cons of _____ style versus _____ style" might be less opinion based, but as your question currently stands it is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the harm in using the late static binding functions I use them heavily in an ORM i have written but i do record the class name in a var on the class at each level because I have needed it for some tasks. I think you are trying to get a collection of items dependent on what you class you statically give the factory? Here is my crack at solving what I think you are asking. I do this by always using the public method on the abstract class, and defining the protected method on the class you are building as each of these may handle the input differently.

```
abstract class AbstractData {
    protected $_abstractClassData;

    public static final function factory($rawData) 
    {
        return static::_createCollectionFromRawData($rawData);
    }
}   

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractData {
    protected $_concreteClassData;
    protected static function _createCollectionFromRawData($rows) {
        $collection = array();
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $collection[] = new static($row); //If you havnt defined a constructor on this class it will use your AbstractData one.
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}


$collection = ConcreteClass::factory($rawData);
```

Comment: Yes, currently I do exactly the same thing as you do, but I have been told this is not quite a good practice since it might cause problems in the future when another collections/concrete classes are introduced.

Comment: Static will always bind at the level it is called which is why I store a static function that gets the class name so if I extend them later on I can manage the differences.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment, what I meant was the fact that static classes/methods shouldn't be used (not the late and early binding with self/static). So I think the problem here is that we are trying to make a collection that holds homogeneous objects which is instantiated from the object itself and that is not a good practice. It is much better I guess to create a collection class and pass as first parameter to its constructor ConcreteClass::class and then the data, this way we make in a way Generics in PHP